# Adding an existing vue js app to my existing .net core project?

Tags: c#, azure, vue.js, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I've developed a web api (C# .Net core), and (separately, in an entirely different directory/project) I have a client app (vue.js). I should've *possibly* had this in the same solution to start with but I don't.

I am running the web api in azure, it works fine. And I can run my vue js app anywhere and it can call the web api, also fine.

### Question

How can I deploy my vue.js app to the same app service as my web api. They were developed separately since I intend to pass the vue.js app into phonegap shortly and treat it as a separate piece of work, but for the purposes of the web and not mobile, I need both vue.js and .net core to run on the same domain/app service and don't really want to integrate them.

### What I've Tried

I have ran 'npm run build' on my vue app and have the dist folder, I've tried adding that to the root of the .net core project before publishing but I can't seem to hit the page when I navigate to the azure address.

Comment: `net core project before publishing but I can't seem to hit the page when I navigate to the azure address.` - any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A brute force way is to FTP the contents of your Vue app dist folder to the wwwroot folder in your Azure Web App.